# HTML, CSS, & JavaScript on Classic Google Sites - Why Video Recording Not Working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sites

There is this code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Recording_a_media_element#JavaScript_content) that I am wanting to upload to Classic Google Sites. (The code is at the very bottom of the link that you can click on.)

I can get the HTML and CSS parts up and running to do the video recorder but the JavaScript part I have no idea why it is not working. The code goes in that order.

I can get some JavaScript to do other stuff but not this. I type in < script > "Copied and Pasted JavaScript Code" < /script> when using the code from the site linked above but no success.

> What am I doing wrong? How do I get this JavaScript part up and running?

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<html lang="en-US">
<div class="left">
  <div id="startButton" class="button">
    Start
  </div>
  <h2>Preview</h2>
  <video id="preview" width="160" height="120" autoplay muted></video>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div id="stopButton" class="button">
    Stop
  </div>
  <h2>Recording</h2>
  <video id="recording" width="160" height="120" controls></video>
  <a id="downloadButton" class="button">
    Download
  </a>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <pre id="log"></pre>
</div>
</html>
<!-- CSS -->
<script> //css
body {
  font: 14px "Open Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

video {
  margin-top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.bottom {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
</script>
<!-- JavaScript (Doesn't Work) -->
<script>
let preview = document.getElementById("preview");
let recording = document.getElementById("recording");
let startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
let stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
let downloadButton = document.getElementById("downloadButton");
let logElement = document.getElementById("log");

let recordingTimeMS = 5000;
function log(msg) {
  logElement.innerHTML += msg + "\n";
}
function wait(delayInMS) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayInMS));
}
function startRecording(stream, lengthInMS) {
  let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  let data = [];
 
  recorder.ondataavailable = event => data.push(event.data);
  recorder.start();
  log(recorder.state + " for " + (lengthInMS/1000) + " seconds...");
 
  let stopped = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    recorder.onstop = resolve;
    recorder.onerror = event => reject(event.name);
  });

  let recorded = wait(lengthInMS).then(
    () => recorder.state == "recording" && recorder.stop()
  );
 
  return Promise.all([
    stopped,
    recorded
  ])
  .then(() => data);
}
function stop(stream) {
  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
}
startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
  }).then(stream => {
    preview.srcObject = stream;
    downloadButton.href = stream;
    preview.captureStream = preview.captureStream || preview.mozCaptureStream;
    return new Promise(resolve => preview.onplaying = resolve);
  }).then(() => startRecording(preview.captureStream(), recordingTimeMS))
  .then (recordedChunks => {
    let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/webm" });
    recording.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
    downloadButton.href = recording.src;
    downloadButton.download = "RecordedVideo.webm";
    
    log("Successfully recorded " + recordedBlob.size + " bytes of " +
        recordedBlob.type + " media.");
  })
  .catch(log);
}, false);stopButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  stop(preview.srcObject);
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: You've put the CSS in a script tag, btw.

Comment: How do you put the CSS part in then? I thought that was how you do it. Or do I just do that for JavaScript? There is something off I think with that because right now there is no way for it to discern JavaScript and the CSS part. However, I am having trouble typing that in because it is just an HTML box that allows you to type it all in.

Comment: `<style> //CSS </style>`

Comment: Do you know how to do that with JavaScript as well?

Comment: JavaScript belongs in a script tag, like you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so from what I can see, the code is actually right and without any issue, if you are putting it all in a single HTML file, you might want to add a head tag and then put the CSS styling in there inside a  tag instead of a  tag.

And Add the JS script inside the body tag at the end of the code, and it should run the code.

I have added the code that works below so you can compare it to your code and see where the difference is :)

```html
    <html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
      font: 14px "Open Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
      }
    
      video {
      margin-top: 2px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      }
    
      .button {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      width: 160px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 2px;
      padding-bottom: 4px;
      color: white;
      background-color: darkgreen;
      text-decoration: none;
      }
    
      h2 {
      margin-bottom: 4px;
      }
    
      .left {
      margin-right: 10px;
      float: left;
      width: 160px;
      padding: 0px;
      }
    
      .right {
      margin-left: 10px;
      float: left;
      width: 160px;
      padding: 0px;
      }
    
      .bottom {
      clear: both;
      padding-top: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="left">
    <div id="startButton" class="button">
      Start
    </div>
    <h2>Preview</h2>
    <video id="preview" width="160" height="120" autoplay muted></video>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    <div id="stopButton" class="button">
      Stop
    </div>
    <h2>Recording</h2>
    <video id="recording" width="160" height="120" controls></video>
    <a id="downloadButton" class="button">
      Download
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
    <pre id="log"></pre>
    </div>

    <script>
      let preview = document.getElementById("preview");
      let recording = document.getElementById("recording");
      let startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
      let stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
      let downloadButton = document.getElementById("downloadButton");
      let logElement = document.getElementById("log");
      
      let recordingTimeMS = 5000;
      function log(msg) {
        logElement.innerHTML += msg + "\n";
      }
      function wait(delayInMS) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayInMS));
      }
      function startRecording(stream, lengthInMS) {
        let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        let data = [];
      
        recorder.ondataavailable = event => data.push(event.data);
        recorder.start();
        log(recorder.state + " for " + (lengthInMS/1000) + " seconds...");
      
        let stopped = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          recorder.onstop = resolve;
          recorder.onerror = event => reject(event.name);
        });
      
        let recorded = wait(lengthInMS).then(
          () => recorder.state == "recording" && recorder.stop()
        );
      
        return Promise.all([
          stopped,
          recorded
        ])
        .then(() => data);
      }
      function stop(stream) {
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
      }
      startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: true,
          audio: true
        }).then(stream => {
          preview.srcObject = stream;
          downloadButton.href = stream;
          preview.captureStream = preview.captureStream || preview.mozCaptureStream;
          return new Promise(resolve => preview.onplaying = resolve);
        }).then(() => startRecording(preview.captureStream(), recordingTimeMS))
        .then (recordedChunks => {
          let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/webm" });
          recording.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
          downloadButton.href = recording.src;
          downloadButton.download = "RecordedVideo.webm";
          
          log("Successfully recorded " + recordedBlob.size + " bytes of " +
              recordedBlob.type + " media.");
        })
        .catch(log);
      }, false);stopButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        stop(preview.srcObject);
      }, false);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now it says, NotAllowedError: Permission denied

Comment: Did you try to run it on StackOverflow itself or on your browser?

Comment: I did that on classic Google Sites. When I Run Code Snippet on your answer I can't get it to work either. It says SecurityError: Invalid security origin when I click on "start"

Comment: There are probably security settings which do not allow the javascript to run, try copying the code and save it in an HTML file and run it on your local browser and it should work

Comment: I'll try that. Are you saying save the HTML separately as a file on your desktop? Then run it on Classic Google Sites. How can I run the file on Classic Google Sites if I do that?

Comment: I did run the file separately by saving it on my desktop, I am not very sure about classic google sites but this is a good page which can tell you how to add HTML on your classic google site, https://www.steegle.com/websites/google-sites-howtos/html-box, and you will have to see if you can run the javascript or not or if it will give you security issues

Comment: I do know how to do that as I have seen that document before. I appreciate your help. I am trying to get it to run on Classic Google Sites and make it compatible with that. I need help in the way that I can get it to run on Classic Google Sites rather than on the desktop though.